# Remove format from string object in python 3.3.1?

Tags: python, string, format

I've had no luck on google, possibly because im not sure how to word it:

```
>>> for k, v in a[0].__dict__.items(): s += '{}={},'.format(k, v)
>>> s
'client_id=123abc,id=123,name=name,distribution=Ubuntu,api_key=abc123,'
```

Now i need to pass the above information into a function:

```
>>> function(s)
```

I dont get an exception but the preset variables the function is expecting such as 'client_id' remain blank because the function is seeing one long string.

How do I get the variable to echo (string) rather than ('string')?

I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: It does not, since nothing is being echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**` [keyword argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to pass the dictionary to the function as if they were keyword arguments:

```
function(**a[0].__dict__)
```